# run a function on each page

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter app is multilingual and I want to redirect users to their pages, by checking IP address.

I should check it at the top of all pages (i know i can set a session or cookie, but i want to check it on all pages); before any views or other.

Where should i put my code (function)? on `Startup` file or `Loader`? or create an extension or plugin and load it on `Startup`? if it can be done by an extension or plugin, how can I create it? (i've searched, but didn't find a useful tutorial)

Thanks.

Comment: your main controller before you load the view or the first line of your view

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz: i've a lot of different controllers, none of them isn't global and doesn't run on each page

Comment: By the way, in case you didn't know, CodeIgniter has a Language class that you can use for multilingual content. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Comment: @sikander: Thanks, but what about templates? LTR to RTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a main front controller you can put your code in there. But a better way to do it would be to use CodeIgniters built in functionality to extend the core - hooks!

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Just select the point you want your script to be activated and take it from there.